# jQuery pjax and google analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am using PJAX https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax and I was wondering since the whole page does not change what would be the best way to track analytics with google analytics?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT: Please note, this is no longer the case. See comment below.**

Defunkts jquery-pjax will actually handle this for you by default (for google analytics at least). Essentially whenever a pjax page load gets invoked, it'll tell the gaq object to log the new page.

The code it uses to do so looks like this:

```
// Google Analytics support
if ( (options.replace || options.push) && window._gaq )
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])
```

Comment: This is no longer true as of [this commit](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/commit/d1ed57262a1ada5fdeeafc56b6df1b54029c5acc). Now you need to   use events to handle the tracking yourself. An example on how to do this using YUI can be found [here](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/pjax/#adding-analytics-support), and can serve as a guide as to how to implement it with jquery-pjax.

Answer (score 41):

The accepted answer is no longer valid because as Ruy Diaz commented, this was removed from PJAX [in this commit](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/commit/d1ed57262a1ada5fdeeafc56b6df1b54029c5acc).

Here is my solution. On the **pjax:end** event, set the GA location, and send a pageview.

The pjax:end event is used because it is triggered both "upon following a pjaxed link" (loading from server) and "on back/forward navigation" (loading from cache). See [pjax events documentation](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events)

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
    ga('set', 'location', window.location.href);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

Or using the old version of GA

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
    if( window._gaq ) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', window.location.href]);
    }
});
```

I had to manually set the location variable because it wasn't picking up that it changed.

Comment: Should probably use `pjax:end` otherwise only first page loads are tracked.

Comment: @Koen looking through the old PJAX code, they had placed it under `pjax:success` so I will edit my answer to reflect that

Comment: `pjax:success` would miss cached pages and `pjax:start` would also be triggered for pages that don't exist, which both are undesired effects. `pjax:end` is triggered simultanuously with `pjax:success` here https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/jquery.pjax.js#L217 and after a state is restored here: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/jquery.pjax.js#L448 This means `pjax:end` is the desired event to bind the pageview to.

Answer (score 2):

Read this http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html and http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncMigrationExamples.html

Google Analytics' _trackPageview is a function for use on ga.js tracked sites that allows you to track events on your site that do not generate a pageview. Using the _trackPageview JavaScript, you can assign a specific page filename to Flash events, JavaScript events, file downloads, outbound links, and more, like this `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/home/landingPage']);`

On successful ajax request you need just to tell GA the 'URL' of the 'page'.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that!

Comment: Just as a heads up, although the above code is correct the "jquery-pjax" script already includes code to keep Google analytics updated. Putting your own call in as well could end up with pages getting logged twice.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @andrewtweber is almost correct, but `pjax:complete` is only triggered after page loads, not on restored pages (e.g. navigating using back button).

Thus the event that should be used is `pjax:end`:

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
    ga('send', 'pageview', window.location.href);
});
```

Or when using the legacy version of Google Analytics:

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', window.location.href]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use PJAX for more than entire page loads and each page load can actually generate several PJAX requests.

To work across the site safely, I submit an event only when the URL changes. This doesn't capture refreshes, but it's better than sending 3x+ hits per page load.

```
href = window.location.href;

if (window.LAST_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_LOCATION !== href) {
  window.LAST_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_LOCATION = href;
  ga('set', 'location', href);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  console.log("Analytics: sending hit, this is a new url: " + href);
} else {
  console.log("Analytics: not sending hit; same url as before: " + href);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

location.href didn't work for me, I'm using:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash);
```